# How to use prompt and Date object together?

Tags: javascript, date

I want a user to be able to enter a date for **new Date** object by using **prompt**. When I initiate a date like this

> var dob = new Date("April 2, 1984");

it works, but if I use prompt it becomes invalid.

```
var urDate = prompt('Date of birth (Ex.:January 3)');
var urYear = prompt('Date of birth (Ex.:1933)');
var dob = new Date(urDate,urYear);
document.write(dob);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) You should not use the built–in parser, manually parse strings with your own function or a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate two values `urDate` and `urYear` like this:

```
var urDate = prompt('Date of birth (Ex.:January 3)');
var urYear = prompt('Date of birth (Ex.:1933)');
var dob = new Date(`${urDate} ${urYear}`);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is because your Date function works with a single string parameter while you are using it with 2 parameters the second time.